# Can one Gershgorin circle (only) contain all eigenvalues, when the other circles are not contained in it

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, random-matrices, eigenvalues

In short, following a question from my students, I am trying to find a special case where all the eigenvalues of a matrix lie within **only** one circle, but not in the others, **and** the other circles are not completely contained in it.

---

## Reminder:  Gershgorin circle theorem

Given a matrix $A\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$, define the disks $D_1,\ldots,D_n$ as follows:
$$D_i = \Bigl\{ z : |z-a_{ii}|\le \sum_{j\ne i} |a_{ij}|\Bigr\}.$$ 
The theorem states that all eigenvalues of $A$ lie within (at least) one of the disks.  Moreover, if a connected component of the union of the disks contains $k$ disks, then exactly $k$ eigenvalues of $A$ lie in that union.

---

I am trying to find an example where all eigenvalues lie within only one circle (of course, all circles must partially overlap for this).

### For $n=2$

Such an example is easy to find. 
For instance,
$
A=\begin{bmatrix}
7 & 9 \\
-5 & -5
\end{bmatrix}
$ has two eigenvalues $\left\{1+3j, 1-3j\right\}$, which are only inside one Gershgorin circle, as illustrated below:

[image: 2x2 example]

### For $n\ge 3$

I could find many examples (by simulation) where one circle **completely contains** all other circles:

[image: 3x3 example]

But I am looking for an example where the circles overlap, **but are not all contained inside one of the circles**. Like in following (hand made) graphs:

[image: Interesting case]

I already randomized billions of such graphs without any success, so I am beginning wonder:

**Is there an interesting mathematical property making this case impossible?**

Comment: I guess a related question would be: can a Gershgorin circle *not intersect* with any other circle that contains an eigenvalue.